# Restar diferentes registros de una misma tabla

Tags: ms-access, sql, subconsultas

Buen dia, tengo una base de datos en Access llamada `cartera` que tiene los siguientes campos y registros:

```
idCartera, noCredito, nombre, mes, reserva

1, 1, "Juan", 1, 500;
3, 2, "Sebastian", 1, 600;
2, 1, "Juan", 2, 300;
4, 2, "Sebastian", 2, 200;
```

(El numero 1 representa a Enero; el 2, a Febrero)

Lo que quiero es mostrar la resta del campo `reserva` de cada mes. O sea `500 - 300` y `600 - 200`

Por el momento tengo la consulta

```
SELECT idCartera, noCredito, nombre, reserva, 

( (SELECT reserva FROM cartera WHERE mes = 1) - (reserva))

FROM cartera WHERE mes = 2
```

Que me genera el error **Esta subconsulta puede devolver como máximo un registro**

El resultado que espero seria:

```
2, 1, "Juan", 2, 300, 200
4, 2, "Sebastian", 2, 200, 400
```

De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Tal y como la tienes a mí me funciona perfectamente, ¿tienes algún registro más en la tabla?

Comment: Mas o menos 100 registros de diferentes personas y en ambos meses

Comment: Efectivamente, al meter otro usuario me da ese mismo error, ¿podrías mostrar lo que esperas obtener con otro usuario más? Es que me está sonando a consulta de agrupamiento, pero no termino de entender qué buscas conseguir exactamente...

Comment: Ya edite la publicación con otro usuario. Lo que necesito es la resta de la reserva del mes anterior, menos la resta del mes "actual"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este error aparece porque intentas restar una columna de datos y un número. Como las dimensiones no son compatibles, obtienes este error. De ahí que para un único cliente funcione y para más ya no.

Te propongo 2 consultas encadenadas:

### c2

```
SELECT cartera.idCartera, cartera.nombre, cartera.mes,
cartera.reserva, [mes]-1 AS mes_anterior
FROM cartera
WHERE (((cartera.mes)=2));
```

### c3

```
SELECT c2.idCartera, c2.noCredito, c2.nombre, c2.mes, 
c2.reserva, [cartera].[reserva]-[c2].[reserva] AS diferencia
FROM c2 INNER JOIN cartera ON (c2.mes_anterior = cartera.mes) 
AND (c2.noCredito = cartera.noCredito);
```

El resultado obtengo para tu dataset es:

> ```
> idCartera noCredito   nombre  mes reserva diferencia
> 2 1   Juan    2   300,00 €    200,00 €
> 4 2   Sebastian   2   200,00 €    400,00 €
> ```

Espero que te resulte útil. Si tienes cualquier duda, déjamela en los comentarios y así dejaremos mejor documentada la respuesta.

Comment: Me falto mencionarlo pero ya edite la pregunta. Porque en la tabla hay muchos registros con personas diferentes `noCredito` ingresados. Ademas que la consulta la usaré para mostrarla en una tabla

Comment: Sí, está claro, como quieres el listado de créditos es de agrupamiento y totales... parece divertida, a ver si me sale... :) Ahora modifico la respuesta, dame un momento...

Comment: Tú respuesta es buena y te agradezco. pero realmente necesito poner manualmente cada mes (lo que ya tengo resuelto en la programación), ya que es un `DataGridView` por cada mes..

Comment: Ok, mucho más fácil entonces: desaparece `c1` y en `c2` seleccionas el mes con el que quieras quedarte. Ya he modificado la respuesta. Recuerda que el resultado lo obtienes ejecutando `c3`. Ya me comentas qué tal

Comment: Solo tengo una duda: `c2` debe quedar guardada como consulta en Access y `c3` es la que mandaría a ejecutar desde el sistema. ¿Es asi?

Comment: Efectivamente, `c2` es una consulta (vista o subconulta) intermedia necesaria para que c3 muestre los resultados que necesitas